# Filtering mongoose data on the clientside with EJS based on a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, express, mongoose, ejs

Beginner working on my first project here.

I have 2 Mongoose schematics and models containing `categories` and `products`. I nested the `products` within the `categories` model.

With Node and Express I send all of the categories to my page. Through using EJS and a for-loop I'm able to make a dropdown(select) list with all of the category names.

Now I'm failing when trying to make a list with all of the products contained inside of the selected categories.

I've went from trying to filter it inside the EJS tags, to combining an external script, to sending a AJAX POST request with the selected data. Nothing has worked.

```
The schemas

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    image: String,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    category: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    products: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product"
    }]
});

The route 

app.get("/proposals/create", (req, res) => {
    Category.find({}).populate("products").exec((err, cats) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("createproposal", {cats: cats});
            } 
    });
});

The loop

<select id="catDropdown" class="ui fluid dropdown">
   <option value="">Category</option>
      <% for(i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) { %>
        <option><%= cats[i].name %></option>  
      <% }; %>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new dropdown list based on the selected category? DO you want multilevel dropdown? Give some information

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like a second dropdown menu displaying the products that are nested in the selected category.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you use optgroup, just to have to have your code simple and your data concentrated.

```
<select id="catDropdown" class="ui fluid dropdown">
   <option value="">Category</option>
   <% cats.forEach(category => { %>
   <optgroup label="<%= category.name %>" >
       <% category.products.forEach(product => { %>
           <option> <%= product.name %> </option>
       <% }); %>
   </optgroup>
   <% }); %>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But the list is going to grow alot bigger. I would probably need even more dropdowns in the end. I'm just not sure how to filter the products based on which category I select.